# What should I look for in order to replicate the image in SceneKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, blender

I need to replicate and animate using SceneKit the following object as you can see in the picture.

[image: hyd]

In blender I created the main object but the issue is:

How can I draw those green lines and number ? is it possible in sceneKit? looking for some advise what should I look for in order to replicate the image in SceneKit and being able to animate the line? any advise?

what could be the best approach?

Comment: "what could be the best approach?"  Best approach?  What makes one approach the best of all?

Comment: how you will do it?

Comment: In order to do something similar you need kind of texture that can change. You could probably create a SpriteKit Scene, where you can do all the Stuff required to animate whatever you want, and then use this SpriteKit Scene as an overlay within Scenekit. There are examples how to do this on SO.

Comment: Hi,. Thanks  a lot for this advice I try out what you mentioned and looks like is doing what i want.. appreciate your help..